# Azure Infra. deployment guidance

Tags: azure, infrastructure-as-code

Seeking some technical guidance wrt to tools/technology to setup infrastructure in Azure as described in the below article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sap/workloads/high-availability-guide-rhel-ibm-db2-luw

Additionally I need a file share to be setup/mounted on each Linux VM so that any shared files(binaries/scripts etc) can be stored/shared from that file share.

Looking for guidance on what tool/tech (PowerShell, Azure CLI, Puppet, Ansible etc) to use for what piece of this infra.

Answer (score 0):

> Additionally I need a file share to be setup/mounted on each Linux VM so that any shared files(binaries/scripts etc) can be stored/shared from that file share

To mount an `Azure File share` on `Linux VMs` and access the file share, follow the steps below.

1. Go to **Azure Storage account > File share and select your file share > Connect > Linux**

[image]

2. Copy and save the Bash script on your local machine.
3. Send the same `Bash` script to all `Linux VMs` (I used `FileZilla` to transfer the file to `Linux VMs` in my case).

[image]

4. After moving the file, verify its presence in the `Linux VM` using the `ls` command

[image]

5. Set permissions for the Bash script and then execute it.

```
    chmod 777 filesharemount.sh
    ./filesharemount.sh
```

6. After running the script, the Azure File share will be mounted to the Linux VM.
7. Check the `File Share`  in `Linux VM` using below command

```
    df
```

[image]

9. Navigate to `File Share` using below command

```
 cd  /mnt/linux-fileshare
```

9. `Azure File share` is mounted in the `Linux VM`, and you are able to access the files. Follow the same process on all VMs

[image]

[image]

10. I'm able to access files which is in File share in VM2.

[image]

Comment: via Azure portal I am able to do it, but I was looking for automation (for repetitive and consistency)